# Set URL for Submit Page in Controller Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

So I have this url in my site

```
localhost/home-loan
```

And when clicked, it performs the following function from the controller page

```
 mortgage_loans_controller.rb
```

I then fill up a form and click submit. But i want my submit page to have the following url,

```
localhost/home-loan/thank-you
```

But it has `localhost/mortgage_loans/thank_you`

thank_you is also another function in the mortgage_loans_controller.

How can i do this?

Comment: In you `routes.rb` home-load is a resource or just simple path?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
match '/home-loan/thank-you', to: 'your_controller#your_action', as: 'custom_name_for_helper', via: [:post]
```

Place this line inside of the `routes.rb`.

This line says that whenever you doing POST request to the localhost/home-loan/thank-you, execute `your_controller`'s `your_action`.

`as:` options will use `'custom_name_for_helper'` to create path helper, like `custom_name_for_helper_path`.

`via:` option determines which request method used, if you need to handle all types just use `via: :all`

I don't know the structure of your routes.rb, so place this line above all routes, to be sure that it will work.